# How can I limit the pages output with WordToHtmlConverter and HWPFDocument?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm converting a Word/.doc file to HTML and I'd like to be able to get a subset of pages. Is it possible to limit the range of output? I'm open to creating a new HWPFDocument from the original with only the subset of pages or after converting limit the length there.

```
File localFile = ...
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(localFile);
HWPFDocument wordDoc = new HWPFDocument(fis);
Document newDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
WordToHtmlConverter wordToHtmlConverter = new WordToHtmlConverter(newDoc);
wordToHtmlConverter.processDocument(wordDoc);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
transformer.transform(
    new DOMSource(wordToHtmlConverter.getDocument()),
                    new StreamResult(stringWriter));

String htmlString = stringWriter.toString();

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(htmlFile), "UTF-8"));
out.write(htmlString);
out.close();
```

Comment: Please read this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with POI. There is no notion of a page in the HWPF format. Pages are an artifact as the consumer. There are no pages until the consumer renders them, and each client can render pages slightly differently, even between different versions of Word.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's what I thought. Was hoping otherwise, or someone who might have overridden afterProcess() in WordToHtmlConverter to trim somehow...